# Check if string is Spotify URL

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I need to create a function to check if a string is a Spotify URL. I made a simple if statement to check if the string contains part of the Spotify URL, it works, but it's crap. Can somebody show me better approach with Regex or something else.

```
if ( input.indexOf('spotify:') > -1  || input.indexOf('spotify.com')  > -1) {
    console.log('url');
}
```

Spotify URLs come in these three forms:

```
https://play.spotify.com/user/spotifydiscover/playlist/0vL3R9wDeAwmXTTuRATa14
https://open.spotify.com/track/1TZ3z6TBztuY0TLUlJZ8R7
spotify:track:1TZ3z6TBztuY0TLUlJZ8R7
```

Comment: Do you want to know if the URL is for a track/album/artist? Or simply a link to spotify.com?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Wanted just the first part, but would be great to know for which one is it too.

Comment: Updated my answer showing how to grab the URL segments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
/^(spotify:|https://[a-z]+\.spotify\.com/)/
```

http://www.regexr.com/3cl88

With proper JS escaping, as there's quite some slashes in there:

```
var url = 'https://open.spotify.com/track/1TZ3z6TBztuY0TLUlJZ8R7';
console.log(/^(spotify:|https:\/\/[a-z]+\.spotify\.com\/)/.test(url));
// Outputs 'true'
```

Answer (score 2):

Matching:

```
var input = 'https://play.spotify.com/user/spotifydiscover/playlist/0vL3R9wDeAwmXTTuRATa14';
if(/\.spotify\.com/.test(input))
{
     // contains spotify
}
```

Comment: Note that . (dot) matches any single character. This also matches your regexp: "-spotify-com"

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone wants to verify a spotify string, get the ID, and wether it's a track or album, use this expression:

```
const str = "https://open.spotify.com/album/0BwWUstDMUbgq2NYONRqlu?si=5qGtCb3_Qh2SburnU09NtQ";
const regEx = /^(?:spotify:|(?:https?:\/\/(?:open|play)\.spotify\.com\/))(?:embed)?\/?(album|track)(?::|\/)((?:[0-9a-zA-Z]){22})/;
const match = str.match(regEx);
if(match){
    const albumOrTrack = match[1]
    const spotifyID = match[2]
    //albumOrTrack: album
    //spotifyID: 0BwWUstDMUbgq2NYONRqlu
}
```

This will match Spotify links, spotify links from embed code, and Spotify URIs. For a explanation as to how the regular expression works, paste it in https://www.regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

To test if the URL starts with `open` or `play` use:

```
> var url = 'https://play.spotify.com/user/spotifydiscover/playlist/0vL3R9wDeAwmXTTuRATa14';
> var re = /((open|play)\.spotify\.com\/)/;
> console.log(re.test(url));
< true
```

Using `match()` you can retrieve the format of the URL.

```
> console.log(url.match(re));
< ["play.spotify.com/", "play.spotify.com/", "play"]
```

Or:

```
> console.log(url.match(re)[2]);
< "play"
```